# How to keep submit and error message on 2nd column leaving the first column?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

In the form, my first column contains the label, so i require to keep the error and submit elements in the 2nd column, where the input element exist. how to do this? I can use my own css to adjust. But wondering if there is a in-build approach existing with bootstrap..

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" #formSignin="ngForm">
 <div class="page-header">
  <h2>User Sign-in</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="col-sm-4"
  name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name"
  >
  <div *ngIf="formSignin.submitted && !name.valid">Name must to be filled</div>
 </div>
 
 <div class="form-group"> 
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add d-flex class on form group  `<div class="form-group d-flex">`

Keep the input, the error and the submit button in a wrapper div

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal" #formSignin="ngForm">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h2>User Sign-in</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group d-flex">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Name</label>
      <div>
        <input type="text" class="col-sm-4" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
        <div *ngIf="formSignin.submitted && !name.valid">Name must to be filled</div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```